# Android: direct scrolling/ displaying a particular page in ViewPager on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to display a particular page of a ViewPager on button click. It is working but scrolling to that particular page is not smooth i.e. suppose I am at page no. 1 but if I want to go to page no. 5, other pages 2,3,4 also scrolls. I just want to scroll to that particular page. How to do it. I have used the following code, please have a look:

Below code is the FragmentActivity:

```
public class ScreenSlideFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SlidingPageInterface{
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 6;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }
        });
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position, NUM_PAGES, ScreenSlideFragmentActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyToSlideToRespectivePage(int pageNumber) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber, true);
    }
}
```

Below code is the Fragment:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_CURRENT_PAGE = "current_page";
        public static final String ARG_TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT = "total_page_count";
        private int mPageNumber;
        private int mTotalPageCount;
        private static ScreenSlideFragmentActivity mActivity;
        public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber, int totalNoPages, ScreenSlideFragmentActivity activity) {
            Log.e("create", "create called");
            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_CURRENT_PAGE, pageNumber);
            args.putInt(ARG_TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT, totalNoPages);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            mActivity = activity;
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CURRENT_PAGE);
            mTotalPageCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TOTAL_PAGE_COUNT);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

            // Write Logic below to Dynamically Display Buttons as per "total_page_count"

            return rootView;
        }
        public int getPageNumber() {
            return mPageNumber;
        }

        public class HandleDotIVClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {            
                int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                mActivity.notifyToSlideToRespectivePage(tag);
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

I had an application where there was more than 100 pages, and an index page which leads to particular page number. From Index page if i tried to go to 20 page, i can see a blink in the screen which goes from 1 -19 then to 20.

I used the below if i want to go to 5th page

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(4,false);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
```

Which made the scroll stopped and made to go to particular page without showing the other pages and no blink in the screen.

Comment: I see what you did, but are you certain there is no blink? This is a very hacky way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't just scroll ViewPager to particular page without scrolling through other pages.

If you want use custom transition for changing fragments, you should use `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int i, int i1, int i2, int i3)`:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Fragment newFragment = Fragment.newInstance();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                       R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                       R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                       R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);
ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, newFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Fragment enter:

fragment_slide_left_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quint">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="33%" android:toXDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Fragment exit:

fragment_slide_left_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quint">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-33%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not. But the alternate you suggested won't work well for me. I am using **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**. So Fragment.newInstance(); is not available. If you provide the complete code, then that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: There is post about instantiating of Fragments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408 
So, **newInstance()** method is a custom method. There is my example: http://goo.gl/uxKgMK

Comment: Hi voltazor, I got your code. It is about displaying the fragments on button click. My requirement is to display fragments in ViewPager, so that it can slide from left to right and right to left with animation while sliding. And same sliding animation required while I click a button on the view pager. Anyways, Thanks. I am just trying if I can use your code for my requirement.

Comment: I think, in that case, you should write your custom ViewPager, which would implement both variants of transition.

Answer (score 0):

use (`manager.beginTransaction().hide(f).commitNow();`) for hide other pages.

then after finish animation use (`manager.beginTransaction().show(f).commitNow();`)

my code in CustomPagerAdapter

```
for(Fragment f : fragmentList)
{
    if(!current.equals(f) && !newF.equals(f))
        {
            manager.beginTransaction().hide(f).commitNow();
        }
}

viewPager.setCurrentItem(index, byAnimation);
```